# SQL Sum of count across 3 tables

Tags: sql, sql-server

Say you have 3 tables:

Categories

- Category ID
- Name

Products

- Product ID
- Category ID (FK)

Sales

- Product ID (FK)
- Sale date

I'm trying to come up with a query that will result in a data table that shows the total number of sales per category, like:

```
Cat ID | Name | Total Sales
-------|------|-------------
1      | Red  | 35
2      | Blue | 25
```

For bonus points, add a WHERE clause to select within a specific date range on the 'Sale Date' column.

I'm using SQL Server.

Comment: Provide database which are you using and sample data from tables.

Comment: Which DBMS are you using? Postgres? Oracle?

Comment: I'm using MS SQL, thanks for asking.

Comment: What's with the downvotes? If you're going to down vote my question, at least add a comment indicating why.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For SQL-Server could be something like that:

```
SELECT c.CategoryID AS [Cat ID], 
       c.Name AS [Name], 
       COUNT(s.ProductID) AS [Total Sales]
FROM Categories c
LEFT JOIN Products p
   ON c.CategoryID = p.CategoryID
LEFT JOIN Sales s
   ON p.ProductID = s.ProductID
WHERE s.Saledate BETWEEEN startDate and endDate
GROUP BY c.CategoryID, c.Name
```

Comment: Thanks, really good, however it doesn't return the category rows which have 0 sales, any thoughts?

Comment: Check It now, try to use `LEFT JOIN`.

Answer (score 1):

```
select Categories.CatID, Categories.Name, count(*) as TotalSales
from Categories
  join Products ON Categories.CategoryID = Products.CategoryID
  join Sales ON Products.ProductID = Sales.ProductID

WHERE Sales.Saledate BETWEEEN date1 and date2

GROUP BY Categories.CatID, Categories.Name
```